# Jenkins Poll SCM Issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to do something extremely simple with Jenkins. That activates a pipeline when a change to my repo is detected.
I have just 2 settings (shown below).

However, any change to the repo And waiting the required polling time it does not trigger the pipeline?

Am i doing something daft here?

[image]

---

EDITS:

- This is in a docker container. The containers time is UTC and the host is BST based. I have updated the TZ at container run time via `-e JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/London`.
- running a tcpdump on the container I see not traffic (https) outbound to github.
- Poll Log added below.

[image]

Comment: You want to trigger off a change but you are using `Poll SCM` instead, which is not what you want. If you want to trigger off a change/commit/PR, you need to use a hook trigger for whatever SCM you are using.

Comment: So what is the purpose of poll?

Comment: To run the job at a given time interval

Comment: @Perplexabot but scm pools the scm for changes since last build ? Ie commits

Comment: You set up a github hook for the repo by going to GitHub.com or Enterprise or whatever. that then sends Jenkins a message saying this repo had a commit (or pr or whatever you set the hook to trigger off). Jenkins then looks at it's list of jobs and sees which was has GitSCM polling flag set, and runs them. I am only familiar with Git not other SCMs.

Comment: My understanding was you could poll or use a hook? Examples on line suggest you can use poll on its own

Comment: Yes you could use either true. But polling will not run the job when a change is made.

Comment: http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html?m=1 : ) when will it run?

Comment: Your link tells you when the job is fired, "every minute." It is similar to cronstyle scheduling : )

Comment: Yep but why give it the url repo what’s it polling ; )

Comment: I believe the `GitHub project` flag is so that you can quickly access the github repo page from the job page by clicking the github icon on the left side ; ) At least without having the `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling` flag checked. You need that one to trigger off a change. But that's not all you need. You need to set up a github hook. There are two ways to do that, that I know of O_o

Comment: @Perplexabot not sure on this. Bottom line is scm polling should poll the repo for change. Of which is not working in my case

Comment: See https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae

Comment: When using TFS polling, there is an additional tfs polling log on the project page which will report the results of the last poll. I do not know if the git plug-in has a similar feature. Additionally when a tfs project has been disabled, it not only needs to be enabled, but also edited and saved to wake up the polling scheduler.

Comment: Would it be possible to see you "Git polling log" in the case of Jenkins running the poll after the changes are done to you git repo?

Comment: Ive added the log above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the basic `Git` feature, vs the `GutHub project` feature.  I have always had better luck with generic features vs features specific to a particular service provider (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.)  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Wait, does this trigger the job upon a commit/push or is this periodically triggered? It seems to me this is periodically triggered. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Perplexabot this polls SCM to check if there were changes, if so it triggers the build.

Comment: @hakamairi, interesting I did not think it was possible via `Poll SCM`. The only difference I see using this method, is that it DOES NOT trigger a job upon a commit/change, it waits for an interval, checks to see if changes occurred since the last time it polled (it could be a single commit/change or it could be multiple changes/pushes from different devs), and kicks off a job if yes. As opposed to using a github web hook, where the job is triggered as soon as a change occurs. This still doesn't trigger off a change. Crazy that this is the answer.

Comment: @Perplexabot that the definition of polling you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine in Jenkins. Did you try to run the first build manually to check if the Jenkins and Git configurations is working fine or not. If the first manual trigger of the build is successful, then please make another test change in the repo to see if Jenkins is polling SCM or not.

Also, you may want to consider Git WebHook trigger which triggers the Jenkins build when a change is detected in the repo instead of Jenkins polling the SCM.

Comment: Yep manual is fine. Seems that when i create the pipeline. Jenkins sees the first change on the repo. After that nothing.

Comment: @bilcy , his configuration is not fine. He is polling not triggering.

Comment: @perplexabot polling should still work, ie trigger build when chance is found in the repo

Comment: That is true. But in your question you are asking why the job isn't running when a change is made. That won't happen with poll

Comment: 1- Build Periodically: Builds the job periodically no matter a change is made in the repo or not.
2 - Poll SCM: Polls repo for a change. If a change is detected then it triggers/start/build the job.
3 - Webhook - Jenkins does not poll SCM. When a change appears in the repo, the SCM makes HTTP call to Jenkins to trigger the build.

Comment: It is point 2 in your comment that I am trying to get to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by @Jose Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57057753/2791574) is the right one, and here's why.

[Github jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin) does provide the following functionality:

> - Create hyperlinks between your Jenkins projects and GitHub
> - Trigger a job when you push to the repository by groking HTTP POSTs from post-receive hook and optionally auto-managing the hook
>     setup.
> - Report build status result back to github as Commit Status (documented on SO)
> - Base features for other plugins

Whereas the [Git jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) seems to be responsible for SCM polling.

By providing the Github project URL you don't provide the necessary configuration for the git plugin. You still need to [add the `Repository URL` in your `Source Code Management` section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57057753/2791574) if you want to use the `SCM polling`.

Comment: thanks, you do not have the add repo url under source code management in pipelines though.

Comment: @felix001 ok, did it work though? That would be bug material if it wouldn't. Then it would be beneficial to figure out which plugin would be responsible for this one.

Comment: This works for free style but is in pipeline i was trying to get this working.

Comment: Most interesting, if I were you I would report this for the jenkins github plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the checkout of the project in the pipeline. It works for me.

[image]

Comment: I tried using the line `git branch: '*', url: 'https://github.com/rickdonato/cicd-demo-1'` with no luck. Potentially issue is with my syntax...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build periodically, no matter was there commit or not, please, use "Build periodically".
"Poll SCM" works checks if there are changes in the repo and then builds.
So depends what do you want to do.

[image]